# Android device shows microphone is actively being used even though session is paused and audio is disabled

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox, vonage

1. Start publishing to a session, notice that Android OS now reports that camera and microphone is being used by the app, which is fine.

[image]

2. Call session.onPause() followed by publisher.publishAudio = false.
3. (Optional) Move application into background by pressing Home button.
4. Android OS indicates that camera is no longer being used, but microphone is still being used by the application.

[image]

Although it does not affect usability of the app it is bad in terms of user privacy perspective - the user might think the app is still recording audio while it is in background, which is scary.

Is there other methods I can call to turn off the microphone access totally, just like the camera?

Comment: The camera will be released immediately when the app is put to the background( session.onPause()) and microphone will be used by the app for approximately 1 minute because audio will be continue to flow for about 1 minute after the app is put in background. The audio flow stops after 1 minute and microphone will no longer be used by the app. 
I am however going to see if there is a way that we can expose the option to instantly shut off the audio stream when you use onPause.

Comment: For debugging purposes it would be useful if you can include in your question sample code on how you are initialising the session.

Comment: @DevWithZachary thanks for the info! Yes if there is a way to instantly shut off audio stream onPause that would be perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a reply from Tokbox support and they provided a tweak that works as expected!

> For your use case, where you don't want to retain the audio access
> when the app goes into the background, you can try to call
> `AudioDeviceManager.getAudioDevice().stopCapturer()` to stop the
> capturer and it will remove the microphone access. If you do this,
> please make sure to call
> `AudioDeviceManager.getAudioDevice().startCapturer()` when the app comes
> in the foreground.